# How can I cache virtual header files?

Tags: rust, clang, rust-bindgen

I was wondering if it is possible to manually add non-existent header files to the bindgen builder.
The C codebase I'm working with generates some header files during the compilation process, and thus don't contain them in the codebase directly. The clang process requires them though.

Let's say I have a header file which includes `export.hpp` like so:

```
#include "foo/export.hpp"
```

and the compiler would then add something like this during the compilation process:

```
//foo/export.hpp

#ifndef FOO_EXPORT
#define FOO_EXPORT
#endif
```

I am able to work around this by simply creating these files, but this is obviously not ideal as they could interfere with the compilation process.

Comment: This question would greatly benefit from a [mre].